# DynamoDB api omit data type from scan

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

According to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-dynamodb-2011-12-05.html#scan), the result of a scan returns the data type like so:

```
'Items' => [
    [
        '<AttributeName>' => [
            'B' => <string || resource || Psr\Http\Message\StreamInterface>,
            'BS' => [<string || resource || Psr\Http\Message\StreamInterface>, ...],
            'N' => '<string>',
            'NS' => ['<string>', ...],
            'S' => '<string>',
            'SS' => ['<string>', ...],
        ],
    ],
```

So, if I want to access the attribute 'price' on the first item, in PHP, I would do `$result['Items'][0]['price']['N']`. Any way to return the result without the data type?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Just need to use Marshaler.

```
use Aws\DynamoDb\Marshaler;

$dynamodb = $aws_sdk->createDynamoDb();
$marshaler = new Marshaler(); 

$params = [
    'TableName' => $table
];

try {
    while (true) {
        $result = $dynamodb->scan($params);
        foreach ($result['Items'] as $i) {
            $item = $marshaler->unmarshalItem($i);
        }
    }
} catch (DynamoDbException $e) {
    echo "Unable to scan:\n";
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```